# Properties of finite field elements with trace zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

This might be a rather broad question but: **are there any properties that are both necessary and sufficient for finite field elements of trace zero?**

Here, I am defining the trace as the sum of Galois conjugates:

$$ 
\text{Tr}_{\mathbb{F}_{p^n} / \mathbb{F}_p} (x) = x + x^p + x^{p^2} + \cdots + x^{p^{n-1}}. 
$$

The only such characterization I have managed to find is Hilbert's Theorem 90: for $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, $\text{Tr}(\alpha) = 0$ if and only if $\alpha = \beta - \sigma (\beta)$ for $\beta \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ where $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p) = \langle \sigma \rangle$.

I am hoping that there are some obscure (or maybe not-so-obscure) theorems that I am unaware of. Would also very much appreciate pointers in the direction of possible references.

Comment: What would you need such a characterization for? "Trace zero" is already itself a very simple condition, as is the condition given in Hilbert 90.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Mostly out of curiosity. If you have a specific field and a specific element, the trace is easy to compute. However, if you have a more abstract set of elements (for example, elements with minimal polynomials that have certain prescribed coefficients), it's harder to show (directly) that the trace is zero. I was hoping to find some alternative route.

Comment: To answer your curiosity: Hilbert's 90 is valid for any finite Galois extension $L/K$, under cohomological form ; with $G=Gal(L/K)$, it reads $H^1(G, L)=0$ for the additive structure (hence the kernel of the trace), $H^1(G, L^*)=0$ for the multiplicative structure (hence the kernel of the norm). Of course things are more explicit when $G$ is cyclic, as you stated in your post. If moreover $K, L$ are finite, say $K=\mathbf F_q$,  $q$ = a prime power, $G$ is generated by the Frobenius automorphism, hence $Tr(x)=0 $ iff $x=y^q-y$. What more could you demand ?

Comment: Obviously you have the condition that the coefficient of X^{n-1} in the characteristic polynomial is zero.